# how to read data from dat file?

Tags: delphi

how to read data from .dat files ?

i just tried like this memo1.lines.loadfromfile('c:\myfile.dat'); but not worked

Note : File type is binary

can any one please help me :)

Comment: what kind of data has the `myfile.dat` file? this extension can be  text, graphic, audio , or binary data. There is no specific structure for a .DAT file. you must specify the content of that file to help you.

Comment: thanks for reply sir ,its binary data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@radick to show the contents of an binary file in a memo control you must encode o convert the data to valid ASCII characters, to turn it all into text. because you can not load something that is not text into a text control.

you can find a very nice sample from Peter Below in this link.

[read a binary file and display the byte values as ASCII?](https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=944)

[image]
<sub>(source: [swissdelphicenter.ch](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/screenshots/tip944.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStream) descendants from the VCL [Classes unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes) to read binary files.

There are plenty [Delphi TStream reading binary files](http://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+stream+reading+binary+files) examples you can find using Google.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

You might look [at this post](http://www.keyongtech.com/5520914-loadfromfile) as they seem to be discussing this very thing.